# combine two array string to make a list

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am working on my own personal app for minecraft. I would forget what recipe I need, and I would just search, and have it display the recipe.

Now, I have the list and search function with it being alphabetical. Now I am manually adding images, and everything else I need. BUT I think it would be more efficient if I had a array string like this

```
String test1[] = { "diamond", "Iron", "Leather" };
String test2[] = { "Leggings", "Boots", "Helmet", "Chestplate" }
```

and in my list view I want the end result to be like this.

Diamond leggings
Diamond boots
Diamond Helmet
Diamond Chestplate
Iron Leggings
...
...
Gold Leggings
...
...
...

What would I need to do to achieve that? I think it would be ineffecient if I did it like this
test3.add("Diamond Chestplate")
test3.add("Diamond boots")
etc..
..
...

and end up having big list instead where I can combine them.

Comment: Try a couple of nested loops.  Comment again if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could do with nested [`For-Each` Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)(s) like

```
String test1[] = { "Diamond", "Iron", "Leather" };
String test2[] = { "Leggings", "Boots", "Helmet", "Chestplate" };
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (String i : test1) {
    for (String j : test2) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(i);
        sb.append(' ').append(j);
        al.add(sb.toString());
    }
}
System.out.println(al);
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect, I will need this in the future and will be able to compile my list with a lot less line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 nested for loops to merge the arrays:

```
        String test1[] = {"Diamond", "Iron", "Leather"};
        String test2[] = {"Leggings", "Boots", "Helmet", "Chestplate"};

        List<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String str1 : test1) {
            for (String str2 : test2)
                merged.add(str1 + " " + str2);
        }

        System.out.println(merged);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Elliott also answered with nested, too.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious to know that If, I can achieve it in a single loop.
How to do it, and finally I have done it.

```
private static String test1[] = {"Diamond", "Iron", "Leather"};
private static String test2[] = {"Leggings", "Boots", "Helmet", "Chestplate"};

public static void doInSingleLoop() {
        int maxLength = test1.length * test2.length;
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            String t1 = test1[i / test2.length];
            String t2 = test2[i % test2.length];

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(t1);
            sb.append(' ').append(t2);
            al.add(sb.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(al);
    }
```

Comment: This required a change from `String t1 = test1[i / test1.length];` to `String t1 = test1[i / test2.length];`, or it would produce an incorrect result and an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  Edit submitted.

Comment: Also, even when using a single loop, it's still an O(N^2) problem, so this answer is probably not any more efficient than a nested loop.  But it is an important exercise.

Answer (score -1):

Check below example.

```js
public static void main(String[] args) { 
 String firstNameArr[] = { "diamond", "Iron", "Leather" };
    String lastNameArr[] = { "Leggings", "Boots", "Helmet"};
    List<String> fullNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
  
    for (String firstname : firstNameArr) {
     for(String lastName : lastNameArr){
      fullNameList.add((firstname+" "+lastName));
     } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct result.  The output of this code is:
diamond Leggings<br>
Iron Boots<br>
Leather Helmet